# How to write a field to change an existing html (or php) file?

Tags: php, file, sidebar

apologies if this seems like a silly question. I'm very new to coding in general and have little to know knowledge of how write what I'm trying to put together.

I just set up a very simple admin page for my site using php and a mySQL database. I'd like to be able to make some basic fields in the admin page to adjust small details in the sidebar of my site. I currently have my sidebar in a seperate php file, so in order for the change to be site-wide all I would have to do is edit "sidebar.php". What do you think would be the best way to tackle this? My goal is to keep this as simple as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Tackle what? Including the file? I don't understand where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to generate the sidebar of your website dynamically

for example you can create a table in your database that contains a list of your sidebar links, then from your file "sidebar.php" you have to call the database and print out these links or ids
and in the admin panel you will have to create a page with form fields to modify the sidebar table in the database (not the file itself) like update/modify/add links

Comment: Hmm, this seems simple enough. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @user1813605 read more about mysql INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and how to connect to the database with php and get some table value, also you will need some HTML background to print out these values probably

Answer (score 0):

Use `include()`

```
include("[YOURPATH]/sidebar.php");
```

You can use this in all of the `.php` files that you want to.. well.. *include* it in.

Or, using

```
require("[YOURPATH]/sidebar.php");
```

Will end entire script on failure, include() won't.